# How to initialize this dictionary

Tags: c#

I want to initialize a `string,datetime` dictionary, I want a "real" time value for each string. Later I want to insert the strings into drop down list as keys and the datetime as values.

```
1 hour (string)- datetime(1 hour value)  
5 hour (string)- datetime(5 hour value)  
2 days (string)- datetime(2 days value)  
3 weeks (string)-datetime(3 weeks value)
```

How do I make this kind of dictionary?

```
public Dictionary<string,DateTime> TimeStep()
    {
        Dictionary<string,DateTime> timestep = 
        { "1  Hour", "2  Hours", "5  Hours", "10 Hours", "15 Hours", "24 Hours", "Two Days", "Five Days", "Ten Days", "Two Weeks", "Month" };
        return timestep ;        
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried searching? The syntax for a literal dictionary seems like something I could find fairly quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>()
          {
                {"1  Hour", TimeSpan.FromHours(1)},
                {"Two days", TimeSpan.FromDays(2)}
          };
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `DateTime` you should use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
dictionary.Add("1 hour", new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)); //1 hour
dictionary.Add("2 days", new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0));//2 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>() 
{ 
    {"1 hour", TimeSpan.FromHours(1) },
    {"2 hour", TimeSpan.FromHours(2) },
    {"3 hour", TimeSpan.FromHours(3) }
};
```

or use **Add** method of Dictionary as below:

```
Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
testDictionary.Add("1 Hour", TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```